# xmlhttp.responseText; returning whole page html results instead of just list options?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, joomla

I have a joomla component for managing workshops.

In the edit view, I have, among other fields, 3 select lists:

1. topic list
2. level list
3. prize currency

I'm trying to populate level list options depending on what has been selected in topic list options.

So in topic list onchange I've added a call to a .js file containing an AJAX request:

```
var xmlhttp;

function listUpdate(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("jform_work_topic_level_idfk").innerHTML="";
    return;
}
xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
{
    alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
    return;
}
var url = document.URL+"&tid="+str;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
             document.getElementById("jform_work_topic_level_idfk").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
return null;
}
```

It's working properly, and level list options are populated with desired values depending on what has been selected in topic list. The problem is that level list is not just populated with that options BUT ALSO with the options of topic list and prize currency.

I think that it's because xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true); is requesting the url that generates the entire form html and xmlhttp.responseText; is returning back the entire html page code. How can I do to just retrieve the options for level list?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options when it comes to retrieving specific AJAX data.

You can either send a request to the server to only get certain values and let a server-side script split it up. For example, you could load a page with a `GET` argument of `?stuff=a` and tell PHP or a CGI script to filter out extraneous content if `($_GET["stuff"] == "a")`. This is probably the quickest and safest way to do it.

Your second option is to filter it out on the client right when you get the request, though this is slower and more risky.

Apologizes if I misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

*My english is not so good.so please try it to understand.* I faced the same problem in asp.net.
if you have server page (aspx.cs) then remove whole html content from source(.aspx) only server side code should be written in code behind.
i try to show you my code through screen shot.
My javascript and html code is written in html page that is static page and server side 
code written in ".aspx.cs" page and no html content written in ".aspx" only top 1 line will be there that is source code.
[this is .aspx file means source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBIuV.png) and [this is server page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxOWg.png) and the last [this is static page that is html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxKhJ.png)